# How can I fix the illegal characters in path while trying to add a configuration setting in WSO2 CEP Quick Start Guide in Windows?

Tags: xml, windows, path, wso2, wso2-cep

I'm trying to add a configuration setting in WSO2 CEP Execution Manager as the step 12.4 of the "[Quick Start Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-Step12:Configureatemplate)" describes, but it won't be saved and browser says:"Error occurred when saving configurations". As highlighted in the [Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm1re.png) maybe a misconfigured path in a XML file is causing this situation. Did I guess a true reason?
How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1485) in CEP 4.1.0, which occurs on Windows environments. The issue has being fixed in CEP 4.2.0 version which is yet to be released.

Comment: Thank you, @Dilini . Althought I have spent a lot of time to fix it till now, you    bought me a lot else too!